# Converting a sqlite database to sdf file

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

Is there any tool or method present to convert my sqlite database to (*.sdf)? I need this for porting a iPhone project to WP7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This morning a new tool (SQLite2CE) was released which has the express purpose of converting your SQLite databases to SDF while providing implementation classes. Visit http://sqlite2ce.codeplex.com/, read the associated articles and download the tool. The included demo and documentation shows how to incorporate your generated database and classes into a Windows Phone project.

Answer (score 3):

Use sqlite's **dump** command to generate a SQL script and just run this SQL script in your target database.